# HKDF vs TLS PRF. Which of the one is better?

Tags: tls, pseudo-random-function, hkdf

Which of the one ([HKDF](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5869) or [TLS1.1+ PRF](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-5)) is more secure and why?

Comment: Better, in what sense?  More secure, in what sense?  For what purposes?  Under what threat model?  This question is too vague as it stands; I suggest you edit it to make it more specific.

Answer (score 4):

It is unclear if you wanted to compare TLS 1.1 PRF or TLS 1.2 PRF. Different TLS versions have different PRFs. Assuming you meant TLS 1.1 PRF although you linked TLS 1.2 RFC.

### TLS 1.1 PRF

Short: HKDF is commonly a better choice than TLS 1.1 PRF, but not always.

Consider these aspects:

- HKDF is a generic construct.
- HKDF is extract and expand.
- TLS1.1 PRF is just extract or expand.
- TLS1.1 PRF is intended for TLS protocol.
- HKDF can be used with hash functions chosen by the user.
- TLS1.1 PRF uses MD5 and SHA-1 hashes. Thus, it does not allow using stronger hash functions.
- TLS1.1 PRF uses two hash functions which causes extra complexity and complicates security analysis.
- TLS1.2 defined new PRF function to use. (So for purposes of TLS, TLS1.1 PRF has gotten deprecated).

TLS1.1 PRF has been analyzed in [Hash function combiners in TLS and SSL](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2175108.2175131).
Based on this analysis, HKDF, when used with a strong hash function is likely stronger than TLS1.1 PRF.

### TLS1.2 PRF

Comparing HKDF with TLS 1.2's PRF.

[NIST SP 800-108 Recommendation for Key Derivation Functions](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-108/sp800-108.pdf) defines various ways to construct Key Derivation Function:
- Counter Mode
- Feedback Mode
- Double-Pipeline Iteration Mode

For NIST, all these approaches are equally acceptable. The Feedback Mode matches HKDF's Expand phase. The Double-Pipeline Iteration Mode matches TLS 1.2 PRF. Thus we could assume, that TLS 1.2 PRF could be considered to be similar to HKDF's Expand phase if used with the same hash function underlying the hmac.

Purpose of HKDF's extract phase is quoted from RFC 5869:

```
In many applications, the input keying material is not necessarily
distributed uniformly, and the attacker may have some partial
knowledge about it (for example, a Diffie-Hellman value computed by a
key exchange protocol) or even partial control of it (as in some
entropy-gathering applications).  Thus, the goal of the "extract"
stage is to "concentrate" the possibly dispersed entropy of the input
keying material into a short, but cryptographically strong,
pseudorandom key.  In some applications, the input may already be a
good pseudorandom key; in these cases, the "extract" stage is not
necessary, and the "expand" part can be used alone.
```

For applications where extract phase is beneficial (distribution of input keying material is not uniform), HKDF is certainly the way to go.

For other uses, where expand phase is used alone, any one of these two (or in some cases counter mode) from NIST SP 800-108 could be used. (Note: If you use TLS 1.2 PRF outside context of TLS protocol, maybe better define the function in terms of NIST SP 800-108, instead of TLS 1.2 PRF from the RFC).

Short summary:

- If you need extract use HKDF.
- If you need expand only, use functions from NIST SP 800-108.
- Generally you should not use TLS 1.1 PRF except for compatibility with TLS protocol.

Comment: Note that the NIST SP 800-108 specs are more or less used to cover all secure KDF's that are allowed. I've created generic implementations of them and tested them against the test vectors. Those test vectors are not covering everything and are already multiple MB's for each KDF construction that is defined. Specifying the *practical* security level of NIST SP 800-108 is a moot point; there are too many variables. Heck, the KDF's don't even have official names let alone ASN.1 definitions or OID's.

Comment: So you can validate your implementation (say, HSM) to be FIPS compliant, but please don't try to find 2 vendors that implement exactly the same KDF :( Reporting this to NIST resulted in a clear "MEH" from NIST

Comment: @owlstead: I almost agree on your points. However, 2 vendors implementing exactly the same KDF are occasionally found, but this is a result of them implementing support for the same protocol(s) using KDFs. BTW, there are also some [CAVP unofficial KDF test vectors](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cavp/#10) available from NIST, for a preliminary compliance check of implementation. Furthermore, if you have a product in being validated in CAVP (a part of FIPS 140-2), you get to choose a lot of options for KDF, to specifically pinpoint how to test your implementation.